# beautifulsoup find_all() returns empty list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using bs4 to parse xml,however i can use find method to extract tag "w:tl" as I want, but find_all(name="w:tl") method returns empty list while only find_all(lambda e: e.name == "w:tl") returns what as expected i.e. it returns all contents with tag 'w:tl' .But strangely find_all('w') is alright. So why is that?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
openxml = '''
<head>
<p id='p1'>12</p>
<w:tl class='p3'>12</w:tl>
<w:tl class='p3'>11</w:tl>
<w:tl>11</w:tl>
<w:tl>11</w:tl>
<w>11</w>
<w>11</w>
<p></p>
</head>

'''
url_soup = BeautifulSoup(openxml,'lxml')
# #
url_soup.find_all(lambda e: e.name == "w:tl")
url_soup.find_all(name="w:tl")
url_soup.find("w:tbl")
url_soup.find_all(name="w")
```

Comment: Please be clear about what output you're looking for. With your first two `find_all` calls, I get `[<w:tl class="p3">12</w:tl>, <w:tl class="p3">11</w:tl>, <w:tl>11</w:tl>, <w:tl>11</w:tl>]`.

Comment: `url_soup.find_all(name="w:tl")` works for me.  bs4 version 4.8.1

Comment: url_soup.find_all(name="w:tl") returns []   bs4 version 4.8.2.  strange..

Comment: yeah. version 4.8.1 is ok.  after reinstalling 4.8.2,it's ok.